# Why is Kanata Age called a traitor in Kuusen Madoushi?

Tags: sky-wizards-academy

The first episode of *Kūsen Madōshi Kōhosei no Kyōkan* shows Kanata risking his life for his friends. However, when they show him next, they call him a traitor.

The wiki is very unhelpful in this regard.

Why they call him a traitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... no one knows, not as of the end of episode one, anyway. According to the first episode, while everyone else was escaping, something happened with Kanata. Nothing else was revealed other than that, so it's basically all speculation until they reveal it.

Comment: You are right, we don't really know yet. Thank you for trying!

Answer (score 0):

The volume 1's prologue of the light novel gives you a kind of good understanding of why he is a traitor, but beyond that, it isn't discussed much. Assumptions are that after their big battle, he lost his power for combat.

Comment: Would you please explain why he is a traitor, and cite relevant passages from the LN?

Comment: Actually read through it and watched the episode again. Doesn't seem like there were any clues. Thank you for the try tho. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In the start, he basically sacrificed himself to let everyone else escape. It might look as something's wrong when they call him a traitor.

True fact, but actually the first episode has the answer. When he sacrificed himself, that was either somewhere into the future or he did something to acquire his title.

My own speculation is that once a certain episode has been released, we'll be back in the present to see what happened after he risked his life for his teammates.

However, this is extremely flawed because there is no proof of what I am saying.

Comment: I think you are almost right but in the first episode, Chloe describes what happened in battle. Just this one incident made me think you were wrong. If not for this, the logic I think was sound.
Then again I'm speculating as well. I accepted @Azianite because hes right, we are just speculating and don't know it yet. Thanks for the help!